# Check if the same ID already has a checked checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an editable `GridView` for Desktop machines, with people, their PC names and if those are their primary PCs. It looks something like this.

| MachineId | PersonId | PC | IsPrmary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 321 | Machine-123 | true |
| 2 | 323 | Machine-567 | true |
| 3 | 321 | Machine-101 | false |

As of now, on the Editable Grid, I can edit `MachineId="3"` and set `isPrimary="true"` which would mean that `PersonId="321"` now has two primary machines, which should not happen.

The editable gridview can only edit one row at a time, so I was wondering how would I check if the `MachineId` I am editing has a `PersonId` who already has `IsPrimary="checked"`.

This is the code behind I am using for add, which is connected to a simple Save stored procedure that basically just gets the editable values and inserts them using `e.NewValues`:

```
protected void gvMachines_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    int index = gvMachines.EditIndex;
    GridViewRow row = gvMachines.Rows[index];

    Label lblMachineId = (Label)row.FindControl("lblMachineId");
    DropDownList ddlPersonId = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlPersonId");
    Label lblPCName = (Label)row.FindControl("lblPCName");
    CheckBox cbIsPrimary = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("cbIsPrimary");

    e.NewValues["Id"] = lblMachineId.Text;
    e.NewValues["PersonId"] = ddlPersonId.SelectedValue;
    e.NewValues["PCName"] = lblPCName.Text;
    e.NewValues["cbIsPrimary"] = cbIsPrimary.Checked;
}
```

I created an `if (cbIsPrimary.Checked) {}` that displays a warning telling the user to check if the person already has a primary machine allocated, but this is not optimal cause we might have 10 000 people with machines.

This is the stored procedure I am using:

```sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblMachines 
           WHERE [Id] = @Id AND @Id IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    UPDATE tblMachines
    SET [PersonId] = @PersonId,
        [PCName] = @PCName,
        [IsPrimary] = @IsPrimary,
    WHERE ([Id] = @Id AND @Id IS NOT NULL) 
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO tblMachines ([PersonId], [PCName], [IsPrimary])
    VALUES (@PersonId, @PCName, @IsPrimary)      
END
```

Comment: Maybe your stored procedure could check `EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Machines WHERE PersonId=@PersonId AND IsPrimary=1)` when `@cbIsPrimary = 1`? Or you could check it in your function before trying to call the sp

Comment: @Rafalon isn't this again only going to check the Row I am calling the stored procedure on? So essentially, it wont exec if `IsPrimary=1`? I added the SP for more clarity. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Yeah you're right, you need to add another condition, say: `WHERE Id<>@Id AND PersonId=@PersonId AND IsPrimary=1` so you can still change other data when `IsPrimary=1`.